# Html mocking tool

Tags: javascript, html

I need to present some pages to a pro designer, for which I need a tool, presenting my current page built using `JQuery` to a static Html without any references to any Javascript files.

I'm looking for a tool which would allow me to mock up the current page's html and convert all `CSS` attributes `display`, `border`, `source`, etc set dynamically by `Javascript` into styles `style="display: none; border: 1px solid gray;"`. Has anyone seen a tool like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A browser does that. Any style added by javascript will be in the style attribute in the HTML element on the rendered page.

I know for certain Chrome behaves this way. You can just copy the HTML from the developers toolbox.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually very easy to serialize the current state of the DOM:

```
$('html')[0].outerHTML
```

You'll have to add the `DOCTYPE` back in, however.

[Demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/HHmzm/)